# Best case in quickhull algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, convex-hull

I would like to ask about quickhull in the best case scenario. Basically I got the idea of quickhull and know why the worst case and average case is O(n^2) and O (nlogn), respectively.

However, does the best case in quickhull happen when the set of leftmost points and the set fo rightmost points have the same amount of points?

As a result, T(n)=T(n/2)+O(n)?

Is it like this and the complexity is T(nlogn)? Can you tell me how did the best case happen and its efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

Best case happens when each partition is almost balanced. So we have

T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n).

which leads us to

T(n) = O(n log(n)).

This would occur with randomly distributed points.